# How to increase the value of a variable incrementally without a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
OPEN_APP (state, app, direction) {
  let i = 10

  const mockApp = {
    id: i++
  }
  const container = {
    id: i++,
    children: [
      {
        id: i++,
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: i++,
        name: 'container',
        color: 'black',
        direction: 'column',
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
  // more stuff
}
```

Because it isn't a for loop, all the objects will have the same `id`: `11`. How can I make it so they all have different ones? (e.g. `11`, `12`, `13`, etc.?)

NOTE: I realized that the repeating number was the ID of `mockApp`. How can I increment its `id` each time I run a function?

Comment: They don't? They do for me. You're adding.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/bijanodolu/edit?js,console

Comment: `++` is a **postfix increment operator**, it returns the current variable value and increment it to 1. So in your case the first id must be 10, second 11, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could make `i` with global scope

```
let i = 10;

function OPEN_APP(state, app, direction) {

    const mockApp = {
        id: i++
    }
...
}

OPEN_APP();

OPEN_APP();
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yveuzq82/)

Answer (score 1):

It actually works for me

```
function OPEN_APP (state, app, direction) {
  let i = 10

  let mockApp = {
    id: i++
  }
  let container = {
    id: i++,
    children: [
      {
        id: i++,
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: i++,
        name: 'container',
        color: 'black',
        direction: 'column',
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
  return {mockApp, container}
};

console.log(OPEN_APP());
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dy166w2r/)

Answer (score 1):

Given the requirements of your edited question, you can use a simply function with a counter that abstracts the logic for generating a new identifier.

```
var ID = (function() {
    var counter = 10;

    return {
        getNewId: function() {
            return counter++;
        }
    }
})();

// Or maybe this way
//var i = 0;
//function getNewId() {
//    i++;
//    return i;
//}

OPEN_APP (state, app, direction) {
  const mockApp = {
    id: ID.getNewId()
  }
  const container = {
    id: ID.getNewId(),
    children: [
      {
        id: ID.getNewId(),
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: ID.getNewId(),
        name: 'container',
        color: 'black',
        direction: 'column',
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
  // more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a closure to do that:

```
var getId = (function(){
  var id = 0;
  return function() {
    id += 1;
    return id;
  }
}());
```

when you need a new id, just do:

```
var newid = getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you put something like

```
 id: mockApp.id + 1
```

Comment: Sure, but shouldn't need to. This seems more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't add comments because of my reputation, I'm just trying to help

Comment: No need to apologize. In general the recommendation is that if you can't comment yet, wait until you can :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
let i = 10;
var myObj = [
    {
        id1: ++i
    },
    {
        id2: ++i
    }
];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sure, but shouldn't need to.

Comment: `i = ++i`? Why would you do that?